# Remove From cart Button not working in django?

Tags: django

When i try to remove item from my cart, remove from cart button accessing add-to-cart definition and when i click on remove button, it increase item in the cart means both add-to-cart and remove-from-cart perform same functionality.

here, my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from products.models import Product
from order.models import Order, OrderItem 
from django.utils import timezone

def cart(request):
    return render(request,'order/cart.html')

def add_to_cart(request,product_id):
    item = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=product_id)
    order_item, created = OrderItem.objects.get_or_create(
        item=item,
        user=request.user,
        ordered=False
    )
   order_qs = Order.objects.filter(user = request.user, ordered = False)
   if order_qs.exists():
       order = order_qs[0]
       #check if the order item is in the order
       if order.items.filter(item__id = item.id).exists():
           order_item.quantity += 1
           order_item.save()
       else:
           order.items.add(order_item)

   else:
       ordered_date = timezone.now()
       order = Order.objects.create(user = request.user, ordered_date = ordered_date)
       order.items.add(order_item)
   return redirect("/products/"+ str(product_id))

def remove_from_cart(request,product_id):
    item = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=product_id)
    order_qs = Order.objects.filter(user = request.user, ordered = False)
if order_qs.exists():
    order = order_qs[0]
    #check if the order item is in the order
    if order.items.filter(item__id = item.id).exists():
        order_item= OrderItem.objects.filter(
                item=item,
                user=request.user,
                ordered=False
            )[0]
        order.items.clear(order_item)
    else:
        #add a message that user does not contain order item
        return redirect("/products/"+ str(product_id))    
else:
    #add a message that user does not have an order
    return redirect("/products/"+ str(product_id))    
return redirect("/products/"+ str(product_id))
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns =[
    path('cart',views.cart,name='cart'),
    path('<int:product_id>',views.add_to_cart,name='add-to-cart'),
    path('<int:product_id>',views.remove_from_cart,name='remove-from-cart'),
]
```

here my html page product.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} {% block content%}
<div id="breadcrumbs">
        <div class="container">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="{% url 'index'%}">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="{% url 'products'%}">Products</a></li>
            <li>{{ product.name }}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- / container -->
</div>
<!-- / body -->

<div id="body">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="content" class="full">
            <div class="product">
                <div class="image">
                    <img src="{{ product.photo.url}}" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="details">
                    <h1>{{ product.name }}</h1>
                    <h4>${{ product.price }}</h4>
                    <div class="entry">
                        <p>Product Type: {{product.type }}</p>
                        <div class="tabs">
                            <div class="nav">
                                <ul>
                                    <li class="active"><a href="#desc">Description</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#spec">Specification</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#ret">Returns</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="tab-content active" id="desc">
                                <p>{{ product.description }}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="tab-content" id="spec">
                                <p>{{ product.specification }}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="tab-content" id="ret">
                                <p>Product eligible for return with in {{ product.returns }} Days.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="actions">
                        <label>Quantity:</label>
                        <select><option>1</option></select>
                        <a href="{% url 'add-to-cart' product.id %}" class="btn-grey">Add to cart</a>
                    </div>
                    <a href="{% url 'remove-from-cart' product.id %}" class="btn-grey">Remove From cart</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- / content -->
    </div>
    <!-- / container -->
</div>
<!-- / body -->
```

{% endblock %}

Comment: you are with the same URL pattern for add to cart and remove views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because your URL path for add/remove are exactly the same so your resolver is by default using the add to cart path. You can either:
A) Use the same URL for both and include a parameter to help you figure out which method to use
B) Use unique URL paths for add vs remove

Heres the django documentation for further info:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/

Comment: Thank You Very Much